# Next.js Middleware matcher, only use when path contains string (%)

Tags: next.js

I have a problem where some website redirects to my website with all entities encoded. I can't change it on their end so I wanted to fix it with a middleware.

Anyone has an idea how i can use the Next.js middleware to only invoke when the path contains a encoded string?

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log('invoked middleware', request.nextUrl.pathname)
  const decoded = decodeURIComponent(request.nextUrl.pathname)
  if (decoded !== request.nextUrl.pathname) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(decoded, request.url).href)
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '//%/', // this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: You should check the URL inside the `middleware` handler instead, then redirect if needed.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is because I want to avoid invocations, the could become expensive since this is handles a lot of traffic.